# what are the applications software I have downlaod after I downloaded ubuntu 13.04

Tags: alternative

I am new on ubuntu and want use it. I switched to Ubuntu 13.04 from windows 7.
I would like to which application soft- wares do I need in order to have all I had in windows specially adobe flash alternative software

Answer (score 0):

you can have adobe flash on your ubuntu too (if you ticked the "install flash" during installation, you have flash installed, if not, open software-center and look for `ubuntu-restricted-addones` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. those two packages contains flash and codecs you may need.

those packages are not shipped with normal ubuntu installation since they are not open - source software.